# Using createProxyMiddleware with variable inputs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using `createProxyMiddleware` to make my connection to an external api. I have 2 paths that are the nearly identical, but one of the paths I have to input 2 parameters. I am having issue with how to get the proxy middleware working with the path that has input parameters.

This is the middleware:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/assets",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https://api.cryptowat.ch",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
  app.use(
    "/markets",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https://api.cryptowat.ch",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

The `app.use( "/markets"` one is the problem. This is the markets call that works:

```
export const fetchMarkets = createAsyncThunk(
"markets/fetchMarkets",
  async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/markets`);
    return res.data;
  }
);
```

The one I can't get to work is this one because right after `/markets` are inputs from the `priceObj` :

```
export const fetchCoin = createAsyncThunk(
"coin/fetchCoin",
  async (priceObj) => {
    const { exchange, pair } = priceObj;
    const res = await axios.get(
      `/markets/${exchange}/${pair}/price`
    );
    return res.data;
  }
);
```

Any ideas on how to make this second call work with the middleware. It works fine if I just paste it in the browser with hardcoded parameters. Running through axios and the middleware I get a 404. I realize there should be another proxy to `"/markets` for this second call but don't know how to set that proxy up.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was a misnamed variable deconstructed from my `priceObj` it should have been `coinPair` rather than `pair` which made it undefined in my path.